# YUY2 scale algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, image-processing

Is anyone at hand with the YUY2 packed format scale routine in C/C++, without intermediary conversions to another color space? I cannot use any libraries like IPP, because its an embedded linux system...

Ideally such function should have this declaration:

bool YUY2_scale( uint8_t *in_buf, int in_width, int in_height, int in_linesize, uint8_t *out_buf, int out_width, int out_height, int out_linesize );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `libswscale` from the FFmpeg/libav/mplayer projects. It's the best there is.

Comment: Cant use any 3rd party libraries

Comment: Sure it has resize. That's where the whole "scale" name comes from.